# Ugh! The extra SQUARE!

Tags: geometry

Can you split this figure into two congruent pieces with a line? The line need not be straight. :D

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cut satisfies the criteria (though I'm not sure if it's the only solution):

> [image: something fishy...]

Answer (score 2):

> [image: answer]
>
>  The cut is the red line.
>  That green rectangle is a helper to make sure that, they are split in half!

Comment: Sorry! I made a huge mistake. I meant "Could you split this into two congruent shapes." Entirely my mistake. +1 For the currently correct Solution, though. Sorry about that.